# DatePickeDialog displays one month greater in android

Tags: android, datetime, jodatime, datepickerdialog

When i press the button to display the DatePickerDialog, the dialog displays one month greater. For instance, if i initiate with the current date like this(with the DateTime of joda library):

```
   DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Athens");

   DateTime dt = new DateTime(zone);


   int year = dt.getYear();
   int month = dt.getMonthOfYear();
   int day = dt.getDayOfMonth();
```

which is  07/08/2014, the date dialog displays one month greater 07/09/2014.
I do not understand why this happens.

The fragment which represents the datePickerFragment is:

```
 @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

        @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
        TextView txtDate;
        GlobalData appState;


         public DatePickerFragment(TextView txtDate) {
            super();
            this.txtDate = txtDate;
        }

        @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
                DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Athens");
                DateTime dt = new DateTime(zone);

                int year = dt.getYear();
                int month = dt.getMonthOfYear();
                int day = dt.getDayOfMonth();

                Log.i("DatePickerFragment day month year", day +" "+ month + " "+ year + "");

                // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
                return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
            }

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                appState.setDateUserFrom(year, month, day);

                Log.i("Date day month yerar", "Date changed." +  day+" " + month + " " +year);
                txtDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day)
                       .append("-").append(month).append("-").append(year)
                       .append(" "));
            }



    }
```

Comment: Usually the month is less by one (Talking about Java) that is by Design although.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[DatePickerDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html) takes `monthOfYear` that is `0 to 11` [0 for Jan... 11 for Dec], and your `DateTime` returns `1 to 12`. So you need to do `-1` with month value.

Use this:

```
return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month - 1, day);
```

Comment: Please explain why this behavior, instead of subtracting a month from the calendar.

Comment: I tried to do new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month - 1, day);. The dialog displays right 07-08-2014 but the month passed to onDateSet is one month lesser than the input date (07-08-14), namely 07-07-2014

Comment: You then need to add +1 again since you use Joda instead of Java Date.

Comment: Yes Julian Liebl is correct, and why not you use Calender to get date?? Is there any specific reason?

Comment: @ByzantineFailure Subtracting the month from the calendar would be wrong. The days of the week would be off. For example, 03-18-14 Jodatime is equivalent to 02-18-14 in the `Calendar` class in java (MM-dd-YY). It would make more sense to just subtract the month value before sending it into the `DatePickerDialog`

Comment: Exactly that is my point, in the above a month is being subtracted. Instead of explaining why the behavior as quoted by the OP

Comment: So, joda library has months from 1 to 12, thus i should do month -1 into the onCreateDialog and then month + 1 into the onDateSet. I tried it and it's working! Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
                DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Athens");
                DateTime dt = new DateTime(zone);

                int year = dt.getYear();
                int month = dt.getMonthOfYear()-1;
                int day = dt.getDayOfMonth();

                Log.i("DatePickerFragment day month year", day +" "+ month + " "+ year + "");

                // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
                return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
            }
```

Month in date picker starts with zero. So you should subtract one from the getMonthOfYear() to set it on datepicker.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess. Joda month starts at 1 for january but java date at 0? So if you use the current date init with joda the date picker will show the wrong month. Easy solution:

```
month = dt.getMonthOfYear() - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it's worked:

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Athens");

       DateTime dt = new DateTime(zone);


       int year = dt.getYear();
       int month = dt.getMonth();
       int day = dt.getDayOfMonth();
```

OR

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Athens");

   DateTime dt = new DateTime(zone);


   int year = dt.getYear();
   int month = dt.getMonthOfYear() - 1;
   int day = dt.getDayOfMonth();
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. The dialog displays right 07-08-2014 but the month passed to onDateSet is one month lesser than the input date (07-08-14), namely 07-07-2014

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the reason behind this is because the Android DatePickerDialog expects 0 based month values. Jodatime return them as you would expect it (more human friendly). So just subtract 1 from the month.

Just to clarify, most date functions/libraries are designed with 0 based month values by default. The exception is where explicitly noted, or third party libraries like Jodatime, which make working with date stuff a joy.